# Bit datatype matches any string of numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql, data-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have a column in my Database of datatype bit. It contains only 1 or 0. If I match this column in a where clause against '0' it just brings back the rows with 0. However if I have this column and match it against a string of random numbers it will bring back rows wherever the column is 1. Why is this the case?

```
SELECT  
aBitColumn
FROM aTableName
where aBitColumn='7256'
```

Comment: check this-https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1039328-338-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, SQL Server does not generally convert strings to bits.  So, what you are seeing is the conversion of an integer to a bit.  The single quotes don't matter.

The convention is that any number other than `0` is converted to the bit `1`.

I would instead suggest doing the conversion in the other direction:

```
where convert(varchar(255), aBitColumn) = '7256'
```

Don't rely on implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

> Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1.

[From Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)